# Express function $Q_t=(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})^{1/\rho}$ in growth rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Does anyone have a clue, how to express this equation (CES production function) step-by-step in growth rates:

CES in levels form: $Q_t=(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})^{1/\rho}$
Here are my steps:

1. take a logarithm:
   $$lnQ_{t}=1/{\rho} * ln(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})$$
2. differentiate in time:
   $$q_t=1 * \frac{d(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})dt}{\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho}}$$
3. substitute $V_{t}=(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})$
   $$q_t= \frac{d(\delta L_{t}^{\rho})dt}{V_{t}}+\frac{d((1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})dt}{V_{t}}$$

And now I am at my wits end... Does anyone know how I can proceed?

The growth rates form should look this way(lower case letters denoting the growth rates):
$q_t=l_t(\frac{\delta L_{t}^{\rho}}{V_t})+k_t(\frac{(1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho}}{V_t})$ where $V_{t}=(\delta L_{t}^{\rho} + (1-\delta) K_{t}^{\rho})$

Comment: What is the exercise word by word?

Comment: @callculus here is the exercise in a study done by Felipe & McCombie: http://www.jesusfelipe.com/download/The%20CES%20production%20function.pdf    page 1229