# Does $d(a L_t^\rho) \,dt = a L_t^\rho \ln(L_t/L_{t-1})$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to take a time derivative here and I am not sure if the following is true? Does anyone know what kind of time derivative rule was used here?

Does $d(a L_t^\rho)\,dt = a L_t^\rho \ln(L_t/L_{t-1})$?

Comment: what is $L_t$ and I assume all the others are constants?

Comment: @HenryLee L(t) refers to labour input in time

Comment: so is $L_t=L(t)$ etc.?

Comment: Here is the whole issue... I thought I figured out the first couple of steps but now I am stuck sadly...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136158/express-function-q-t-delta-l-t-rho-1-delta-k-t-rho-1-rho?noredirect=1#comment8558085_4136158

Answer (score 0):

I believe what has been used is a discrete form of differentiation. The definition of the derivative is:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
What people normally do when solving such problems numerically is:
$$df_t\,dt=\frac{f_t-f_{t-1}}{dt}dt=f_t-f_{t-1}$$
where the subscript $t$ represents a discrete point in time, and $t-1$ is the previous timestep with $dt$ being the difference between the two

Comment: Precisely! It should be a discrete form of differentiation. Do you believe I solved the problem correctly then? Thanks for your help Henry Lee!

Comment: @Adam I am confused as to where the natural log came from but the exact methods used in these problems depends on the situation

Comment: what I am trying to solve here is merely the last step in more of a complex problem... I do not know where the natual log came from either, that is why I was asking if the equation above is correct. May I point you to my other question (which is the problem in its whole length)? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136158/express-function-q-t-delta-l-t-rho-1-delta-k-t-rho1-rho

Comment: @Adam I have had a look at the question. This is not my area of expertise so the notation confuses me slightly (used to lower case letters being mass-specific quantities). In this case is delta variable?

Comment: delta is not a variable. it should be a parameter

Comment: as far as the lower case letters... q(t), l(t), k(t) are the same as for example (Q(t1)-Q(t0))/Q(t0) or equally ln(Qt1/Qt0)